# How to install Das U-Boot legacy boot in x86 IBM-PC?

Tags: boot, boot-loader, intel, u-boot, x86

Das U-Boot is [both](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Das_U-Boot) first and second stage bootloader, as FSBL in a IBM-PC it must fit into the first [446 bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootloader#First-stage_boot_loader) (or less) before MBR in the first sector.

There is also a 1.5 stage boot loader that uses the FSBL code to read 31,744 bytes from disk and jump to it (sector 1 to 62, as DOS complience first partition can start in sector 63). I believe it is not the case of U-Boot.

I'm not looking for UEFI neither kexec alike, and I would rather if it doesn't require coreboot or other bootloader code, I have [read](https://superuser.com/questions/723112/is-it-possible-to-boot-linux-on-a-x86-machine-with-u-boot) it is possible but noone made it clear how.

Which config should I use? Chromebook Link or Edison? Will it generate a 446 bytes chunk to put in MBR? should I put something in sector 1 to 62? I believe it will not fit in 1.5 stage, how is it suppose to find the rest in disk?

Comment: Intel Edison has natively been using U-Boot. The issue with it that the binary (starting addresses, supported stuff, etc) is not so compatible with legacy firmware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although U-Boot supports x86 *hardware*, it does not include support for x86 BIOS *firmware*.

Therefore, the first step in using U-Boot on a legacy x86 PC would be to replace the BIOS with your own custom firmware that includes the first stage of U-Boot.

After you’ve done that, the old BIOS boot conventions like loading a 446-byte boot code from block #0 of the first hard disk won’t apply any more, and U-Boot’s conventions will be used instead.

Of course, replacing the BIOS requires that your custom firmware must first be able to handle the initialization of your system’s chipset, and testing and enabling the RAM after a cold start. On PC hardware, this can be a bigger challenge than you expected, as chipset programming documentation may not be easily available for all PC chipsets.

U-Boot is not a BIOS-compatible bootloader nor an easy drop-in replacement for BIOS; when its documentation says it supports x86, it only means that U-Boot can readily be integrated with hardware projects that use an x86 processor on custom hardware.

It looks like you’re perhaps confusing the terminology that was specific to GRUB Legacy (first stage, second stage, stage 1.5) with more generic systems design terminology for boot loaders.

In the systems design sense, on a legacy x86 PC with a goal of running Linux, *the BIOS* is the first-stage bootloader: it is arranged in ROM (or flash EEPROM) to be the first thing the processor will execute after a cold reset, and its job is to initialize the necessary hardware and load a relatively compact program from a fixed or otherwise well-defined location.

In the systems design sense, the entirety of GRUB would be a second-stage bootloader. GRUB Legacy is also divided in components that are called “stages”, but these are just internal divisions of GRUB that were created to work around legacy BIOS restrictions; GRUB stages are not the same as the systems design *first/second stage bootloader* terminology.

Comment: Is that why it is said it would be possible as coreboot payload? But if it requires coreboot I could use the one without u-boot... What is the most lightweight bootloader that is BIOS compliance?

Comment: It seems barebox is a u-boot fork that is [BIOS-compliance](https://www.barebox.org/doc/latest/boards/x86.html), someone with the same problem as I should take a look at it.

Comment: If you need a lightweight BIOS-based bootloader, the old [LILO](https://www.joonet.de/lilo/) might also be worth a look.